# Will changing the CPU show up in system or device manager?

Tags: windows, cpu, device-manager

I recently bought a new computer, and was told that the CPU had been swapped out for a better (Core i7 7700) processor, however this does not show up in system or the device manager. 
I have uninstalled all CPUs from the device manager and rebooted the computer, to no avail.

This may be a noob question so any help is appreciated.

Also, if possible I would like to find out without taking apart the computer.

I have Windows 10.

Comment: Sounds like you may have gotten ripped off. If it's not showing in System and Device Manager, that means you don't have an i7 7700. What processor does it list? And you don't need to take it apart. Whatever processor it lists in either of those two locations is the processor you have.

Comment: it lists the i5 7300 its a quad core so 4 of them. Thanks very much for the answer, i'll follow up on it

Comment: @n8te Post it as an answer.

Comment: You could also validate using CPU-Z software. Just another way to confirm it.

Comment: Bu the way is it a laptop? According to Intel i5-7200HQ is a laptop CPU.  In this case, and this is really really far feched, if you have Core i7 7700HQ with hyperthreading disabed it may report as Core i5. See Core i5 is just Core i7 with no hyperthreading. There is an option in your BIOS/UEFI settings to enabe hyperthreading so you can try that too.

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić Windows should not (and does not) determine a CPU's model based on how many cores it has. Such would be a foolish confusion between CPU *model* and *capabilities*.

Comment: @Twisty I mentioned that I saw manually underclocked Sempron report as Athlon, but a long time ago. Was it a Windows, CPU or motherboard cofusion or the cobinatiom of any I don't know, therefore it's possible but "really really far feched".

Answer (score 2):

> Will changing the CPU show up in system or device manager?

### Yes!

Whatever CPU is currently installed in your system will be shown in the System control panel app. It's not necessary to uninstall the CPU from Device Manager for the new CPU to be detected; Windows will detect it automatically.

If you want an extra sense of assurance that the CPU reported by Windows is what's actually installed on your computer (without opening it), then access your system's BIOS/UEFI and note the CPU information reported there.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, your computer will definitely show up the model of your CPU within the system.

If you have been told that your computer's processor has been swapped out for a better one, then there should be some indication of this in the System tab.

Go to Control Panel, System and Security, then System. You should see something akin to the image below.

If your claimed processor is not listed in this view, then I am sorry to say that you have probably been conned by the person who sold you the processor upgrade.

I have never, ever, ever heard of a case where the processor is incorrectly reporting its model name to the system.

[image: System View]

Comment: I did see underclocked Sempron report as Athlon, but that was 12 years ago.